# Which version of Visual Studio 2010 does support Database Projects: Ultimate edition, Premium or Professional?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, database-project

In my project we had VisualStudio 2008 Development Edition as IDE. We have normal projects but also use Database Projects for SQL Server. The reason we had VisualStudio 2008 Ultimate is that Professional version didn't had support for DBProjects.

**Which version of Visual Studio 2010 does support Database Projects: Ultimate edition, Premium or Professional?**

Thanks,
Cad

EDIT: Here ww.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/10/19/VS-TFS-2010-Beta-2-has-arrived.aspx you can see a nice comparison card of features. But still not sure 100%.

Comment: It seems that VisualStudio 2010 Professional allows you to open Database projects. But yo need Premium edition to be able to deploy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premium and Ultimate support a wide range of database development features. You can deploy database, track changes (with TFS), unit test, generate test data. These feature are only supported in the two above mentioned versions. However, Professional versions (there are two of them) support only data access features, but not the mentioned ones.

For more information have a look at this VS2010 version comparison guide http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Answer (score 2):

Given this [comparison grid](http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/en-GB/Microsoft/Design-+-Developer/Visual-Studio-2010/Visual-Studio-Comparison-Grid), it looks like you should be fine with Premium.

On the other hand, I've only got Professional installed, and I still have the following options for database projects:

- SQL Server Data-tier application
- Visual Basic SQL CLR Database Project
- C# SQL CLR Database Project

Is one of those the project type you're after? Basically it depends on what you want to do...